# jquery (ajax) click makes php script to run multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having a button, and when is clicked, it renders (with the help of ajax), the content of a php script (basically it's a contact form). My problem is that when the button is clicked, this calls the php script twice or more times. I've tried many solutions, but none worked.

HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="" id="contact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contact').off();
    // the above line I've replaced it with:
    // 1. $('#contact').off('click');
    // 2. $('#contact').unbind();
    // 3. $('#contact').unbind('click');
    $('#contact').click(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contact.php",
            success: function(html){
                $('#content').html(html);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The response I get when I run the page which contains the HTML and JS:

[image]

The contact.php receives the data send with ajax (from index.php - the page which contains the above code), and then sends the new contact to another php script (which is a class), who stores the new contact in the database, and gives back (to contact.php) a response.

contact.php

```
<form id="form">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nume" value="<?php echo Escape::esc($nume);?>" style="pointer-events:none;background:#EFEFEF;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prenume" value="<?php echo Escape::esc($prenume);?>" style="pointer-events:none;background:#EFEFEF;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="mesaj" rows="20" data-toggle="mesaj" data-placement="bottom" title="Va rog introduceti mesajul dvs."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="return validate();" style="margin-left:15px;">TRIMITE</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
    var nume    = $('#nume').val();
    var prenume = $('#prenume').val();
    var mesaj   = $('#mesaj').val().trim();

    if (mesaj == '' || mesaj.length < 3){
        $(function(){
            $('[data-toggle="mesaj"]').tooltip();
            document.getElementById('mesaj').focus();
        });
        return false;
    }
    $('#form').off();// here I tried to unbind all the previous submit events too
    $('#form').on('submit',function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../app/classes/Contact.php",
            data: {nume:nume, prenume:prenume, mesaj:mesaj},
            success: function(html){
                $('#content').html(html);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
</script>
```

Any tip is welcomed! Thank you!

Comment: so first ajax will print the form, second ajax to process the form submit, and your problem with second one .. right ?

Comment: I guess it's with the 1st one. That is called when I press CONTACT in the navbar. The 2nd one is called after an user fills in the contact form and presses Send button.

Comment: could you try to change the contact id to some thing else

Comment: Try to implement the JavaScript from the contact.php in your index.php and just render the HTML part, when the user clicks on "Contact"

Comment: @jahller the result is the same. any other tip, please?

Comment: so why you use ajax to show the form fields ,, just print the form always and hide it or show it from js (if the fields is dynamic and the form is not always same, then use ajax)

Comment: @Mohammad Alabed I'm doing this because I have a lot of buttons in the navbar. And when each of them is pressed I want to bring the content of each in the same div of the index.php script, w/o refreshing the page.

Comment: @DanCostinel so doing same, print all contents (lets say you have 5 different blocks) as hidden html, then show what you like and hide the other in the same container by js like this (http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-use-css-and-jquery-to-hide-and-show-tab-content/)

Comment: @Mohammed Alabed I can't doing that, because in the index.php page, I have many buttons (some of them are located in the navar, some of them are located at the bottom of the page). So, when the index.php page first loads, there is another content that must be displayed in the `<div id="content"></div>` div, and not the contact form. Then, if it's the case, when the CONTACT button is pressed, the current content of the `<div id="content"></div>` div is discarded, and the contact form should be displayed.

Comment: Have you tried to move `e.preventDefault();` **before** the ajax call ?

Comment: @Sebastien I just did that right now, and the problem is the same :(

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, JavaScript does not execute functions sequentially by nature.  In your first jQuery snippet it looks like your code assumes that it will first unbind any events bound to `$('#contact')` and then create a new binding, but that's not necessarily true.

Also, the `off()` command only works if you bound the event to the element using a corresponding `on()` command, but your code uses `click()` instead of `on()`.

You may want to try something like this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#contact').on('click', function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contact.php",
            success: function(html){
                $('#content').html(html);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Using `$('#contact').on('click', function(e) ...` will allow you to call `$('#contact').off()` after the `e.preventDefault();` if you want to try to use that to troubleshoot the double-posting problem.

I'm not sure that will fix your issue, but hopefully it's a step in the right direction.